# p:dataTable selectionMode for view and edit

Tags: jsf, primefaces

In `p:dataTable` `selectionMode="..."` use to I try `Add`,`View` and `Edit`. In below code to I use `Add` operation then how do I try `View` and `Edit` operation in `p:dataTable`?

```
<p:dataTable id="checkboxDT" var="car" value="#{dtSelectionView.cars6}" selection="#{dtSelectionView.selectedCars}" rowKey="#{car.id}" style="margin-bottom:0">
        <f:facet name="header">
            Checkbox
        </f:facet>
        <p:column selectionMode="multiple" style="width:16px;text-align:center"/>
        <p:column headerText="Id">
            <h:outputText value="#{car.id}" disabled="#{dtSelectionView.fieldDisabled} />
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Year">
            <h:outputText value="#{car.year}" disabled="#{dtSelectionView.fieldDisabled} />
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Brand">
            <h:outputText value="#{car.brand}" disabled="#{dtSelectionView.fieldDisabled}/>
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Color">
            <h:outputText value="#{car.color}" disabled="#{dtSelectionView.fieldDisabled}/>
        </p:column>
        <p:column><p:commandButton value="Edit" 
        action="#{dtSelectionView.editAction} update="checkboxDT"/></p:column>
        <f:facet name="footer">
            <p:commandButton process="checkboxDT" update=":form:multiCarDetail" icon="ui-icon-search" value="View" oncomplete="PF('multiCarDialog').show()" />
        </f:facet>
</p:dataTable>
```

Comment: selectionMode does not have 'view' and 'edit' so what do you mean?

Comment: In add action to save dataTable details and edit button press previous dataTable records and checkbox needed becuase that reference to select checkbox and save to edited records

Comment: there is no edit button in your code

Comment: Even after the edit, I fail to see the actual problem. Seems all just 'work' to do…